# TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have Keras model in format **.h5**. I want to read it with this code:

```
#model.h5 is name of mode, tf and modellib is read

custom_objects={'tf': tf,'BatchNorm':modellib.BatchNorm,'ProposalLayer':
                modellib.ProposalLayer} 
model=tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5")
```

But I getting an error

> TypeError: init() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'proposal_count' and 'nms_threshold'

I have the newest version of TensorFlow (2.2). Changing the version of TensorFlow is not helping.

Comment: Seems that the custom layers you use are not implemented correctly, missing get_config() method most likely.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error and the custom objects i think you are tring to save the model of [matterport/MaskRcnn](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN), I ran in the same issue.
The problem was that the custom layer ProposalLayer isn't correctly defined.

The parameters of the custom layer **init** should be initialized by default, otherwise an error may be reported:

```
TypeError: init() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'proposal_count' and 'nms_threshold'
```

I solved the issue in this way:

first of all i load the standard configuration in this way:

```
from mrcnn import config as config_std
```

thene i modify the init of the custom layer "ProposalLayer"

```
    def __init__(self,  proposal_count = config_std.Config.POST_NMS_ROIS_TRAINING, 
                    nms_threshold = config_std.Config.RPN_NMS_THRESHOLD, 
                    config=None, **kwargs):
```

I simply put the standard config passed in build function of the framework directly as default argument as keras need.